# How to trigger the onchange event of jquery from the second time of drop down selection change using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown which has select by default in it.If now user selects any other value other than select for the first time my change event should not be triggered and my change event should work from second time.Is there any way to do this

Currently my trigger change event which i had written is working from the first time of drop down selection change only but it should work from second time

```
$("#ddl1").on('change', function () {
        if ($("#ddl1").val() != "-1") {
            $('#txtmode').val('');
            $('#txtcolor').val('');
            $('#txtcustomization').val('');
            $('#txtexpecteddate).val('');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the information in a variable :

```
var secondChange = false;
$("#ddl1").on('change', function () {
   if(secondChange){
    if ($("#ddl1").val() != "-1") {
        $('#txtmode').val('');
        $('#txtcolor').val('');
        $('#txtcustomization').val('');
        $('#txtexpecteddate).val('');
    }
   }
   else{
    secondChange = true;
   }
});
```

Or, if you want that occurs in your if condition :

```
   var secondChange = false;
  $("#ddl1").on('change', function () {

    if ($("#ddl1").val() != "-1") {

      if(secondChange){

        $('#txtmode').val('');
        $('#txtcolor').val('');
        $('#txtcustomization').val('');
        $('#txtexpecteddate).val('');

       } 
       else{
        secondChange = true;
       } 
     }    
});
```